# Photoshop: how can I access other directories beside DCIM?

Tags: images

Screenshots apps store their images in different locations. For example:

- ShootMe uses SD card/ShootMe
- The native screenshot tool in ICS uses SD card/Pictures/Screenshots
- etc

I am wondering, is the Photoshop for Android able to access other directories beside SD card/DCIM, because all the pictures I can see are the ones taken from the camera? Obviously this makes screenshots editing (e.g: cropping) difficult.

Comment: There are two very different Adobe PhotoShop apps for Android, the free, limited PhotoShop Express that lets you slightly tweak pictures, and the full (paid) Photoshop Touch. Which one are you having problems with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asssuming you mean [Adobe Photoshop Express](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.psmobile) it is set by default to only show you Camera pictures. You should be able to change a setting to make it look at the rest of your phone's storage.

Open Photoshop Express, press <kbd>Menu</kbd> (on ICS press the `...` in the corner of the screen), select **More** and then **Settings** and scroll down to near the bottom where you should see the option **Show camera photos only in Phone view**, take the tick out of the box and press <kbd>Back</kbd> to get back to the main Photoshop Express window where you should already see it filling up with all the pictures it can find.

Comment: Ah I forgot to mention that I'm using PhotoShop Express. BTW, it works. Thanks :)